# How include more variables to show and hide icon

Tags: javascript

I Have the following script that works fine just for one div ("dois"), but I want to include another div\variable for this code. How would be this code to work properly for 2 divs?

```
document.getElementById("_bar_Id_").onclick = function(c) {
  var x = document.getElementById("dois");
  if (x.style.visibility === "hidden") {
  x.style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    x.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to create another `.onclick` listener as follows:

```js
document.getElementById("_bar_Id_").onclick = function(c) {
  //for element with id: dois
  let x = document.getElementById("dois");
  if (x.style.visibility === "hidden") {
  x.style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    x.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
  //for element with id: dois2
  x = document.getElementById("dois2");
  if (x.style.visibility === "hidden") {
  x.style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    x.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
  }
```

This would obviously not scale when you have a lot of elements you need to change on click. So you should have an array of the `id`s of all the elements you want to listen to and add an event listener for each of them as follows:

```js
const elementIds = ["dois", "dois2", "dois3", "dois4",];

document.getElementById("_bar_Id_").onclick = function(c) {
  for (id of elementIds) {
    const x = document.getElementById(id);
    if (x.style.visibility === "hidden") {
    x.style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
      x.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
  }
}
```

and now whenever you have a new div with and `id` you want to listen to, you just have to add them to the `elementIds` array.

Even further improvement would be how you select the items you change the properties of. With the last solution, whenever you need to add another element, you will have to come up with a unique `id` and add it to the `elementIds` array.

Alternatively, you could give all the elements you need to change the `visibility` of a common class such as `barClickTarget` and use `getElementsByClassName` to get all elements with that class. Then, now you could just:

**HTML**

```html
<div class="barClickTarget">...</div>
<div class="barClickTarget">...</div>
<div class="barClickTarget">...</div>
```

**JS**

```js
document.getElementById("_bar_Id_").onclick = function(c) {
    const elems = document.getElementsByClassName("barClickTarget");
  for(const x of elems) {
    if (x.style.visibility === "hidden") {
    x.style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
      x.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
  }
}
```

and all you have to do now to add another `barClickTarget` is to add that to the class of the target element.

Comment: Actually I need another variable like this which is another div:  var x = document.getElementById("dois");  and not another _bar_Id_.

Comment: It works in a similar fashion. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: I tried the way you shared using array, but somehow in my browser just works for one 'div' in showing and hiding when clicking the buttom.

Comment: could you update your question to show us that? @Bigboss

Comment: I tried using getElementsByClassName as you suggested and it worked well. Thanks!